# iOS 7 bar button items: custom background images and highlight state darkens image

Tags: ios, ios7

I have a custom theme for my iOS app and on iOS 6 it looks as I want.
But on iOS 7 the OS automatically darkens the background (and the image that I use as the button) itself, so it looks different.

So I have a bar button item with a custom image and the following code:

```
UIImage *navbarButton = [[UIImage imageNamed:@"navbar_button"]
                         resizableImageWithCapInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(1, 1, 1, 1)];
UIImage *navbarButtonHighlight = [[UIImage imageNamed:@"navbar_button_highlight"]
                                  resizableImageWithCapInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(1, 1, 1, 1)];
[[UIBarButtonItem appearance] setBackgroundImage:navbarButton
                                        forState:UIControlStateNormal
                                      barMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
[[UIBarButtonItem appearance] setBackgroundImage:navbarButtonHighlight
                                        forState:UIControlStateHighlighted
                                      barMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
[[UIBarButtonItem appearance] setBackgroundImage:navbarButtonHighlight
                                        forState:UIControlStateSelected
                                      barMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
```

What am I doing wrong / forgetting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if([Utilities iOSVersion] >= 7){

    [self.navigationController.navigationBar setBarTintColor:[UIColor whateverColorYouWant]];

    [self.navigationController.navigationBar setTintColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];

    //translucent is key

    self.navigationController.navigationBar.translucent = NO;
}


/**
 * @return this device OS version
 */
+(int)iOSVersion{

   NSArray *ver = [[UIDevice currentDevice].systemVersion componentsSeparatedByString:@"."];

   return [[ver objectAtIndex:0]intValue];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try doing [[UINavigationBar appearance] setTintColor:[UIColor whiteColor]]. I had a similar problem and this lightened it up.

Comment: Nope, that only changes the icons on the bar items (and I already have a `self.window.tintColor = [UIColor whiteColor];`)

Comment: Oops I meant bakcgroundcolor. Sorry I can't remember exactly as I'm unable to reach my files right now

Comment: I only see `barTintColor` and `tintColor` on the navbar, which both do not work.